# two different version differential Bianchi identity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

There are two different version of differential Bianchi identities,one use the (0,4) curvature tensor:

$$\nabla Rm(X,Y,Z,V,W) + \nabla Rm(X,Y,V,W,Z) + \nabla Rm(X,Y,W,Z,V) = 0\tag{1}$$

another use (1,3) curvature endomorphism :

$$\left(\nabla_{X} R\right)(Y, Z)W+\left(\nabla_{Y} R\right)(Z, X)W+\left(\nabla_{Z} R\right)(X, Y)W=0\tag{2}$$

I try to show these two are the same.I try to deduce (2) from (1).

first since $Rm = R^\flat$,hence (1) is equivalent to:
$$(\nabla R)^\flat(X,Y,Z,V,W) + (\nabla R)^\flat(X,Y,V,W,Z) + (\nabla R)^\flat(X,Y,W,Z,V) = 0$$
where we use $\nabla$ commute with musical isomorphism.

which implies:
$$\langle(\nabla_VR)(X,Y)Z,W\rangle+\langle(\nabla_WR)(X,Y)V,Z\rangle+\langle(\nabla_ZR)(X,Y)W,V\rangle = 0$$

at this point I don't know how to preceed,maybe we need to use symmetry of curvature tensor at this step?

Comment: Have you used the fact that the covariant derivative commutes with the musical isomorphisms?

Comment: @Didier , yes, in this step : $(\nabla R)^\flat(X,Y,Z,V,W) + (\nabla R)^\flat(X,Y,V,W,Z) + (\nabla R)^\flat(X,Y,W,Z,V) = 0
$ I use this fact.

Comment: You should detail your convention on how is built $Rm$ out of $R$ (or vice versa) since it is not universal.

Comment: Oh , $Rm(X,Y,Z,V) = g(R(X,Y)Z,V)$ ,and the curvature endomorphism can be written as $R(X, Y) Z=\nabla_{X} \nabla_{Y} Z-\nabla_{Y} \nabla_{X} Z+\nabla_{[X, Y]} Z$ @Didier

Comment: Could you please details what  is meant by $\nabla Rm (X,Y,Z,V,W)$ also? For some people it is $(\nabla_X Rm)(Y,Z,V,W)$ while for some others it is $(\nabla_WRm)(X,Y,Z,V)$. Some others use the symbol ";" to separate the variable of differentation, e.g, $\nabla Rm(X;Y,Z,V,W)$ means that the covariant derivative is taken with respect to $X$

Comment: $(\nabla_W Rm)(X,Y,Z,V) = \nabla Rm (X,Y,Z,V;W)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Rm}{Rm}$
Let us denote by $R$ the Riemann curvature tensor of type $(1,3)$ and $\Rm$ that of type $(0,4)$. They are related by the formula
$
\Rm(X,Y,Z,T) = g(R(X,Y)Z,T),
$
where $g$ denotes the Riemannian metric.

Usual considerations about Leibniz rule and the compatibility between the Riemannian metric and its Levi-Civita connection gives the equality
$$
(\nabla_X\Rm)(Y,Z,V,W) = g((\nabla_XR)(Y,Z)V,W).
$$
In short, it says that the covariant differentiation commutes with the musical isomorphism. Let us sum this last equality over a cyclic permuation of $(X,Y,Z)$:

\begin{multline}
(\nabla_X\Rm)(Y,Z,V,W)+(\nabla_Y\Rm)(Z,X,V,W)+(\nabla_Z\Rm)(X,Y,V,W) = \\ 
g((\nabla_XR)(Y,Z)V+(\nabla_YR)(Z,X)V+ (\nabla_ZR)(X,Y)V,W).
\end{multline}

Hence, (2) being true is equivalent to
$$\tag{3}
(\nabla_X\Rm)(Y,Z,V,W)+(\nabla_Y\Rm)(Z,X,V,W)+(\nabla_Z\Rm)(X,Y,V,W) =0.
$$

Since $\Rm(A,B,C,D) = \Rm(C,D,A,B)$, so does its covariant derivative: $(\nabla_X\Rm)(A,B,C,D) = (\nabla_X\Rm)(C,D,A,B)$ (this is a direct application of Leibniz rule). Hence, (3) is equivalent to
$$
(\nabla_X\Rm)(V,W,Y,Z)+(\nabla_Y\Rm)(V,W,Z,X)+(\nabla_Z\Rm)(V,W,X,Y) =0,
$$
which is now basically (1) with a suitable relabelling of the variables.

If I may make a small comment: I think the notation $\nabla T (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ for the covariant derivative of a tensor is confusing. I'd rather write $(\nabla_{X_1}T)(X_2,\ldots,X_{n})$ or $(\nabla_{X_n}T)(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})$, which leaves no room for doubt. Some authors (e.g Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine) write $(\nabla T)(X_1;X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ (maybe $(\nabla T)(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1};X_n)$) to emphasis the difference between the direction of differentiation and the other directions.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your kindly help,I didn't realize covariant derivative of curvature tensor also has permutation symmetry before.

Comment: @yili More generally, if $S$ is a symmetric $(1,1)$-tensor, so is $\nabla_XS$, etc.

Comment: Hi Didier, covariant derivative of curvature tensor inherent all the algebra symmetries of curvature tensor correct?